# Get correctly file paths from pipeline in cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell

I wrote small test code:

```
namespace Test {
  using System;
  using System.Management.Automation;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.IO;

  [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Test", DefaultParameterSetName="Path")]
  public sealed class GetTestCommand : PSCmdlet {
    private String[] _paths;
    private Boolean  _wildcards;

    [Parameter(
      ParameterSetName="Path",
      Mandatory=true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true
    )]
    public String[] Path {
      get { return _paths; }
      set {
        _wildcards = true;
        _paths = value;
      }
    }

    [Parameter(
      ParameterSetName="LiteralPath",
      Mandatory=true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=false,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true
    )]
    public String[] LiteralPath {
      get { return _paths; }
      set { _paths = value; }
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord() {
      ProviderInfo pi;

      (from p in _paths
      select new {
        FilePath = (_wildcards ?
          this.SessionState.Path.GetResolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(p, out pi)[0] :
          this.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(p))
      }).ToList()
      .ForEach(i => WriteObject(i.FilePath));
    }
  }
}
```

This works:

```
Get-Test *.txt
```

And this works:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | Get-Test
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Get-Test
```

Please explain me what's wrong, how to fix and what I should to read to deeply understand PowerShell's mechanism.

Comment: Add `[Alias("PSPath")]` to `LiteralPath` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that works with this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you actually did not process the objects you received from `Powershell cmdlet`.
Correct way of doing so is binding received parameter to appropriate type of object and then access its properties, i.e:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Test", DefaultParameterSetName = "Path")]
public sealed class GetTestCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    private FileSystemInfo[] _paths;

    [Parameter(
      ParameterSetName = "Path",
      Mandatory = true,
      Position = 0,
      ValueFromPipeline = true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true
    )]
    public FileSystemInfo[] Path
    {
        get { return _paths; }
        set
        {
            _paths = value;
        }
    }


    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        ProviderInfo pi;

        (from p in _paths
         where (p.GetType() != typeof(DirectoryInfo))
         select new
         {
             FilePath = p.FullName}).ToList()
        .ForEach(i => WriteObject(i.FilePath));
    }
}
```

For future reference you might want to check what type is received from `cmdlet` with `Get-ChildItem | foreach-object -process { $_.GetType() }`.
And what's more, you can actually achieve what you wanted in a same way with `Powershell`, for example: `Get-ChildItem | foreach-object -process { $_.FullName }`.

For having exactly same result with pure `Powershell`, try:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process { if ($_ -isnot [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) { Write-Host $_.FullName } }
```

Comment: At firstly, thank you for your reply but I'm not sure that it's what I'm looking for for my test. I'm just trying to understand how PowerShell works generally.

Comment: What do you mean by 'how PowerShell works generally'? You've created function that accepts parameter(s) of type `String` and then `Process` them. What you did wrong is that you've set type of parameter to `String` while result of `Get-ChildItem` that you pipe into your function returns objects of type `FileSystemInfo`. Since param was of type `String`, you just received every object casted to `.ToString()`. You might actually check that with `Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object -Process { $_.ToString() }`.